# Am I only checking for links of a URL with this java code?

Tags: java, url, hyperlink

I have  a method that takes in URL and finds all the links on that page. 
However I am concerned if it is only taking links as when I check if the links are working or not, some of the links seem strange.
For example if I check the links at www.google.com I get 6 broken links that return no http status code and instead says there is 'no protocol'for that broken link.
I just wouldn't imagine google would have any broken links on its homepage. 
An example of one of the broken links is: /preferences?hl=en 
I can't see where this link is on the google homepage.
I am curious if I am checking just links or is it possible I am extracting code that is not supposed to be a link?

Here is the method that checks the URL for links:

```
public static List getLinks(String uriStr) {

    List result = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create a reader on the html content
    try{
        System.out.println("in the getlinks try");
    URL url = new URI(uriStr).toURL();
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    Reader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

    // Parse the HTML
    EditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
    kit.read(rd, doc, 0);

    // Find all the A elements in the HTML document
    HTMLDocument.Iterator it = doc.getIterator(HTML.Tag.A);
    while (it.isValid()) {
        SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet)it.getAttributes();

        String link = (String)s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
        if (link != null) {
                // Add the link to the result list
                System.out.println(link);
            //System.out.println("link print finished");
            result.add(link);
        }
        //System.out.println(link);
        it.next();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the link that you are getting back.

Looking at your code you are extracting the `href` attribute, which in the case of your example is from the element:

```
<a  class=gbmt href="/preferences?hl=en">Search settings</a>
```

(You can see this link if you click on the bottom right on "Settings", a list should popup with several links)

As you can see the `href` attribute only contains `/preferences?hl=en`, which simply makes it a *relative link*. The full url would be the address of the page you are currently at + the href. In this case:

```
http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en
```

You just need to tweak your code to prepend the argument of your method if the url is relative.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean, I'm just not sure how to code it. if(link != uriStr + the href) add the url to the front of the link. Somwthing like that?

Comment: I would do something like: `if(!"http".regionMatches(true, 0, link, 0, 4)){ link = uriStr + link; }`. This way you don't need to worry about case sensitive links, or hrefs with less than 4 characters. No need to be sorry. Glad to help :)

Comment: So it was working but hit a snag with a url I entered. This was the error message:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String.regionMatches(String.java:1196)
 at LinkChecker.getLinks(LinkChecker.java:129)
 at LinkChecker.main(LinkChecker.java:43)

Comment: Well, that will happen if `link` is `null`. You can always change the condition to be `if(link != null && !"http".regionMatches(true, 0, link, 0, 4)) ...`

Comment: Ah ok, the link was null. Thanks, I didn't understand the problem.